# (Apps Script) Function that receives a cell and a range and checks if the cell value is in the range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following problem, as the title says, I am trying to develop a function that validates if the value of a cell is in a range. It receives as parameters the cell and the range.
But it gives me the type of error that I show below:

I need this **formula to be dragged** to the cells below

```
function buscarValorEnRango(celda, rangoInicial) {
  var hoja = celda.getSheet();
  var filaActual = celda.getRow();
  var rango = hoja.getRange(rangoInicial.getRow(), rangoInicial.getColumn(), filaActual - rangoInicial.getRow() + 1);
  var valores = rango.getValues();
  var valor = celda.getValue();
  for (var i = 0; i < valores.length; i++) {
    if (valores[i][0] == valor) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

TypeError: celda.getSheet is not a function

It would be of great help to me if you could help me
Thanks a lot

I tried to check the type of object that the cell has but to no avail.

Comment: What is `celda` in your script?

Comment: Hi, it's a cell in google sheets. Thanks